# Visual Studio rename files on a directory with cycle for and substitute it with text from a textbox

Tags: vb.net, file, rename, cycle

I need help with the cycle for, when program start should rename files on selected directory but it doesn't.

This is the code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
        Label4.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
        Dim counter = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
        Label5.Text = counter.Count
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim basedir As String = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
        For counter As Integer = 0 To Int(Label5.Text)
            My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(basedir, TextBox1.Text + "x")
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath` returns a normal string. Calling `SelectedPath.Count` **will not** give you how many files are in the directory, but *how many character the string path consists of*.

Secondly, calling `RenameFile(basedir, ...)` won't do anything since `basedir` points to a single directory - **not** the files in the directory.

In order to get a proper file count, AND iterate through the file names you'd have to use something like `Directory.GetFiles(basedir)`.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Label4.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
    Label5.Text = Directory.GetFiles(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath).Count
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim basedir As String = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
    Dim Files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(basedir) 'Declare an array that holds all file paths.
    For counter As Integer = 0 To Files.Length - 1 'Minus one is important here, so that you won't get a "IndexOutOfRangeException".
        My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(Files(counter), TextBox1.Text & counter)
    Next
End Sub
```

`Files(counter)` represents the file that it's currently at. If `counter = 0` then `Files(counter)` would be the first file path in the array, and so on.

One thing I don't understand is why you give the new files the name of whatever you put in `TextBox1` and an `x`. You are currently giving *every* file in that directory the exact same name (which is impossible). Could you tell me what you really are trying to rename them to?

In the mean time I replaced the `x` with `counter`. That will rename them to `<whatever is in TextBox1>0`, `<whatever is in TextBox1>1`, and so on.

---

One last thing, as you might have noticed I put the ampersand (`&`) instead of the plus sign (`+`) in the second parameter of `RenameFile`. Using the ampersand is the recommended way of concatenating strings, as the plus sign could cause exceptions in certain cases.

---

**EDIT:**

To keep the extension of the file you just have to extract it, and then add it to the new name:

```
For counter As Integer = 0 To Files.Length - 1
    Dim FileExtension As String = Path.GetExtension(Files(counter)) 'Keeping the extension.
    My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(Files(counter), TextBox1.Text & counter & FileExtension)
Next
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't say before, anyways this program help me to rename files for a media center, like 1<number on textbox for season x and another 1< the episode number. Now i have another question it's possible to keep the extension of the files ?